# How can I store a bootstrap modal inside a variable?

Tags: php, function

I want to write a php function to generate a Bootstrap modal so I can simply call it to create more modals. Thus reducing code repetition. My first approach was to store all the HTML within a Variable and then return it as shown in the function below.

```
function modal(){
    $build = ' <button type=button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="modal-xl">
                    Test Modal
                </button>';
    $build .= ' <div class="modal fade" id="modal-xl">
                  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Extra Large Modal</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>';
    return $build;
}
```

And then to generate it I would simply do

```
<?=modal()?>
```

My problem with this approach is that although the code is inserted inside my page, I can't seem to be able to open the modal in question.

Anyone has some though? or alternative way of doing so?

I was hoping to create a Builder class for various components like this one.

Comment: And if you echo it? Instead of return?

Comment: @Rustyjim he is echoing it.

Comment: Yes with <?=modal()?> you echo it, but I thought perhaps it made a difference to also echo inside the function. But possibly that makes no difference and you are right. @shaggy

Comment: @Rustyjim no it does not make a difference. And he wrote: the code is inserted inside my page - so the echo part is working right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright for modals, I manage to get it working by using a javascript trigger instead.

```
function modal(){
$build = ' <button type=button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-xl">
                Test Modal
            </button>';
$build .= ' <div class="modal fade" id="modal-xl">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Extra Large Modal</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>';
    $build .= ' <script>
                    $(document).ready(function(){
                        $("#btn-xl").click(function(){
                            $("#modal-xl").modal();
                        });
                    });
                </script>
    ';
return $build;
}
```

Hopefully I won't have to trick bootstrap like this with all other components.

PS. Make sure to load JQuery and Bootstrap Javascript before echoing the function.